# Azure DevOps: Wiki and TFVC repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

**Context:**

I have a project in Azure DevOps where I created a quite extensive wiki. I would like to move a set of pages to another project with an underlying Git structure.

**Problem:**

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=vsts) it should be possible to access the underlying Git repo to access the necessary resources. For the project with Git this works fine but for the project with TFVC I can't access it.

**Question:**

Is there a way to get to the underlying Wiki repository given TFVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but not via the UI / Azure DevOps portal. You need to clone the repository locally, then you have access to the resources and you can then modify and push the changes.

Comment: I concur and, this may be helpful: Clone and update wiki content offline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=vsts